# Не работает max-height для изображения в firefox

Tags: html, firefox, css

```
<img src="mylink" alt="" class="imgcenter">
```

-

```
.imgcenter {
    margin: 5px auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 140px;
    width: expression(this.width > 140 ? 140 : true);
    max-height: 100px;
    width: expression(this.height > 100 ? 100 : true);
}
```

Высота картинки не должна быть больше 100, у Chrome все отлично масштабируемый. В FF не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот тебе пример

[ссылко](http://jsfiddle.net/zXVCS/104/)

вообще на сайтах обычно изначально скриптами (или в редакторах) создают картинки для того чтобы они корректно отображались и имели постоянные величины.

по мне так бессмысленная трата времени